# Runtime environment of the Snap programs

Tags: software-installation, snap

What is the technique used by snap to sandbox programs in `Strict confinement` ?
How much isolation does it provide ?
Does it make use of `chroot` , `apparmor` , etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement?utm_source=insights&utm_campaign=snapd_2_20_classic_post#interfaces):

> Strict confinement uses security features of the Linux kernel, including AppArmor, seccomp and namespaces, to prevent applications and services accessing the wider system.

If a snap with `Strict confinement` wants to access other system resources such as network and camera , it should use `Interfaces`.
As stated [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management) :

> When a snap needs to access a resource outside of its own confinement, it uses an interface. Interfaces enable resources from one snap to be shared with another.
>
> Interfaces are commonly used to enable a snap to access OpenGL acceleration, sound playback or recording, your network and your $HOME directory. But which interfaces a snap requires, and provides, is very much dependent on the type of snap and its own requirements.
>
> To see which interfaces a snap is using, type `snap connections "snapname"`

If you (in fact I) want to install and use a package in non-strict (classical) confinement , you should add the option `--classic` to the `snap install` command and if the classical version of the package is present , it should be installed.